# Copy a single axis of a numpy array by index

Tags: python, numpy

Im looking for an elegant way to extract the values of an single axis of a numpy array by an index. For example:

```
x = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
a = x[0]
b = x[:, 0]
```

Is what i usually do, however i am looking for something like:

```
a = get( x, axis=0, index=0)
b = get( x, axis=1, index=0)
```

Is there some fancy function to do this maybe?

Comment: Do you need this 2d arrays only?  If so, you could easily use transpose.

Comment: It should work für N dimensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) to move the axis you're interested in to the front, then just index into it as normal:

```
def get(x, axis=0, index=0):
    return np.rollaxis(x, axis, 0)[index]

x = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)

assert np.all(get(x, 1, 2) == x[:, 2, :])
```

As Joe correctly pointed out, this returns a view onto `x`. In order to force a copy to be made, you could use the `.copy()` method:

```
cpy = get(x, 1, 2).copy()
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit for the OP's sake: Using `rollaxis` in this manner is a common idiom in numpy.  `np.rollaxis` makes a view rather than a copy, so this technique is just as memory-efficient and fast as writing the indexing expression directly.  It's useful in a lot of cases where you want to operate on an arbitrary axis of a N-dimensional array.  Roll and then operate on the first axis.  Because rolling creates a view, if modifications are made to the "rolled" version, they're made in the original as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `__getitem__` magic method directly to get the same functionally, but with easier support for dynamic arguments. Here is an example that uses the `itertools` package:

```
def get(matrix, axis, index):
    return a.__getitem__(tuple(chain(repeat(slice(None), axis), (index,))))
```

This creates a tuple with a slice object that represents the colon in `a[:]` repeated `axis` times with `index` at the end. I think the tuple generation could be cleaned up, but I can't think of a cleaner way at the moment.

An example usage would be this:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3) # [[0 1 2], [3 4 5], [6 7 8]]
get(a, axis=0, index=0) # [0 1 2]
get(a, axis=1, index=0) # [0 3 6]
get(a, axis=0, index=1) # [3 4 5]
get(a, axis=1, index=1) # [1 4 7]
```